# glOrtho setting view

Tags: opengl

I am duplicating this thread from stackoverflow, please remove it if that is not allowed.

I'm completely new in OpenGL. I have this problem: I have quite a complicated scene, and I am looking at it from the front (default camera position). The way I have seen to move the camera is using the gluLookAt() function to set the point you want to look at, and glTranslate3f() to move the camera position. I need to move the camera with different data - my data is not the point I want to look at - rather, I have the data of the projection plane - determined with a viewing vector and a point in the plane. Is there a way to set the camera using this data rather than a "look at" point?

I am using an ortographic projection (glOrtho()), so everything is projected onto the projection plane.

UPDATE: To be more precise: the point I have is a point in the plane, to which I want to project to. I have in fact not only the plane, but the square to which I need to project, defined. So I have a scene somewhere a space, and a square somewhere away from that scene. I want to project the scene to that square and show that projection on screen. I hope that made it a bit clearer what I need to achieve ... While gluLookAt defines a point in the scene at which to look at, and the position of the eye. While eye is one point in space and projection offers perspective, with ortographic projection, you do not have one point, you have a whole square on which to project to, so how can I define that?

For easier understanding what I am trying to achieve. Here is the image of what glOrtho normally does: [image: glOrtho normal]

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve: 
[image: glOrtho question]

Comment: Just letting you know, you're using a VERY outdated opengl version.

Comment: Ben, it is possible, but how can you tell?

Comment: glOrtho and gluLookAt and a WHOLE bunch of other stuff is no longer used. Opengl has changed almost completely. You can still use an old version, I'm just letting you know in case you want to learn the newest one. Modern opengl has many new features and concepts. You would not be able to make a modern game using this old stuff.

Comment: Don't cross-post between sites. Pick the site you think is most on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to multiply rotation matrix by projection. You can try building quaternion based rotation matrix or by euler angles. Then just do mvp_matrix = rotation_matrix * projection_matrix.